# menus need to made ok for touchscreen

Tags: iphone, hover

About 18 months ago we built a biggish site (for us!) around Joomla. The client was very happy with the site. However, at the time it was decided not to be overly concerned about the mobile market. We incorporated some drop down menus that appear using the "hover" command, based around the good old sucker fish. Perhaps, in retorspect this wasn't he wisest thing!!!

Now our client wants to go "iDevice" friendly - of course, these menus don't work on iPad and iPhones, becuase there is no hover (or so I think!).

A few possible options have occured as to how we can edit the site so that these drop downs either work, or are removed for those devices that don't support hover.

I was wondering if you guys out there could perhaps point us in the right direction before we jump in and start experimenting, since we have not done a lot of mobile work up to this point. Would it be better for us to just do away with the drop-downs for these touch screen devices, or convert the whole lot so it works on "Click" rather than "Hover". Should we be sniffing out the availablity of "hover" as our test? Are there any good resources that you could recommend? How might we best approach this problem?

If you want to see the site its http://www.coinstreet.org/

I/we would really appreciate any pointers!

Comment: i tried the link in safari of iphone simulator and the links dont work as they are not clickable. so i think you should ask the question as more of a web development.

Comment: I can see that it is working now on your site, but how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method to indicate "interest" in a region of the screen on an iPhone or touch-only device is handling taps gestures, which translate as "clicks" on a web page.     One possibility is to use the "long tap" gesture to indicate a hover in your interface.  But probably the best thing (unfortunately) is to redesign the UI to use "click" only, at least for the mobile market.

Comment: Yes, I think we are coming round to the solution of making the top level clickable and doing away with the drop downs all together. i'd like the client to move down the "mobi" site route really, but I think that's not on the agenda. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest version of superfish and it works fine on iPhones and iPads

For some android phones though you need to use the 'long click' gesture to drop down the menu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) its an enhanced suckerfish menu which will work on iphone/pad.

It may that "upgrading" to this will be the quickest option.

Comment: @Mark: Superfish was developed to bring certain other niceties(like IE6 support, the hover "intent" feature etc) to the web interface. It doesn't solve the issue of :hover on touchscreen devices.

Comment: @KaushikGopal While that's true, Superfish does work well with the iPad, using a touch to show things normally shown with hover.

Comment: I'm the author of Superfish and recently did a number of updates to make it work on all Android browsers as perfectly as it does on iOS. Check it out and please spread the word. Android users need this fixed! http://plugins.jquery.com/superfish/